# Loading data effectively in RecycleView

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm populating a list of data and this data is loaded in 3 steps, so after the first step is finsihed I already show the data to the user. Then I update the UI step by step whenever the data loading state changes...

I use a `RecyclerView` to display my data. I could observe, that when the loading of the single steps is very fast, the UI is blocking (especially when the user is currently scrolling very fast)... So I need to group the events and only update the UI every x ms...

With testing I saw, that updating the UI every 150ms seems to look good and fast and does not lead to any visible stuttering.

But I'm not sure how older devices or other devices react.

Does anyone have any experience in this direction and can tell me which value would be good?

**General question**

*Probably the question can be asked even more generally: when updating the UI very frequently, what's the best frequence to use to avoid blocking UI? Or what's the minimum time to wait before updating the UI again*

Answer (score 8):

Your question is very interesting and there are some methods for solving. I just put some solutions here with reference.

**1. Cache your data**

When user scroll, your adapter will query some data from array, from database or network. Due to your slow performance, I guess maybe a problem because long loading data time. So the best method for solving this problem is caching data.

You can cache your data on memory using [LRUCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class and on disk by using [DiskLRUCache](http://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/DiskLruCache.html) There is a Android Guideline for this problem: [Caching bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Psuedo code:

```
if (memoryCache.get(key)) {
   // load data from memory and assign to cell
} else if (diskCache.get(key)) {
   // load data from disk and assign to cell
} else {
  // get data from database or network
  // assign to cell
  // save to memory cache
  // save to disk cache
}
```

**2. Use different thread for loading data**

When you process a long running task affect your UI, you should put off to UI Thread and create new thread for your purpose. You can use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this purpose.

The problem in this method is: while loading data from background, the displayed cell on screen by scroll event need different data. So, when old asynctask object finished work, it assigns old data to your cell. **BUMP!!!**. So you must control your cell's state carefully. There is a nice tutorial: [Process Image Loading In Different Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

**3. Simplify your View**

If you don't use something such as database handling, network request while scrolling, maybe the problem is your view is too complex. You should use this tool:[Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) for checking which your layout file has performance problem. You can also use tool [GPU Overdraw tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/debug-gpu-overdraw/index.html) for checking if many parts on your view has drawn many thing unnecessary.

**4. Detect time for updating data base on frame rate**

You must always keep your frame rate below 60fps. With that frame rate, user will not recognize lag, clunky ... in your view. You can use [GPU Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038787/loading-data-effectively-in-recycleview/35039339#35039339) for checking frame rate. Base on that frame rate, you will decide you should simplify view, optimize `onDraw` method or optimize GPU Drawing (due to overdrawing) for keeping your UI frame rate <= 60fps.

All above methods I have integrated to my project named [ImageUploader](https://github.com/hqt/ImageUploader) . This application uploads image to Flickr service and display list of all uploaded images or view single images.

Google has uploaded a series of [Android Performance Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lxVqqWwTb0&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) teach you many useful things such as caching, batching, useful tips ...

Hope this help :)

Comment: Actually, I have no problem with caching data and updating UI, I use a method similar to your second suggestion, namely I use RXJava + background execution + buffer and only emit my results every 150ms and this is done in a grouped way. This way, I can update the UI quite well... Still, I'm interested in the time span I should use or if there is some time span to use that's well tested or even (maybe officially) suggested...

Comment: PS: of course, handling the cells state is already done as well ;-). Only open question for me is, how often should I update the `RecyclerView`? Or more generally, how often should I update any `View` or is there a maximum or "good" maximum frequency to update views...

Comment: it depends on your data (how complex query, server quantity, network ...) . You must profile your code to know that time span. But **always** keeps your frame rate 60fps. You should use GPU Profiler for checking how current your frame rate is. http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/profile-gpu-rendering/index.html

Comment: It's a very simple update process, the `RecyclerView` does already have all views, so I just update the data in the views (showing a loading indicator, updatig a text)... But doing that every 1ms is overkill of course and will lead to blocking UI... So I just tried some values and 150ms worked quite well. I'll check out the profiler... Still, that will just give me results for my own device...

Comment: @prom85 I have updated my post for updating some tools for profile your application. Let get a try :) Each tool has each own purpose. And maybe many micro performance leads to your layout's lag :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the post is old. But if someone still want to deal with the Loading data effectively in RecycleView, try this library https://github.com/mrHerintsoaHasina/picassiette. It sounds like Picasso or Glide but supports also custom data (not only bitmap). You must migrate your project to androidx.